# ORDER BY FIELD (column_name, (SELECT ))

Tags: mysql, sql, field, sql-order-by

Current query, which doesn't work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
ORDER BY FIELD(sum, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY sum SEPARATOR ',') 
  FROM users
  LIMIT 1
) ASC
```

I want to select `users` by a custom ordering depending on a sum. If I get a result from a query `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY sum SEPARATOR ',') FROM users LIMIT 1` and then add it to the FIELD's 2nd argument, then it works. But when I do that in one query, it doesn't, it just doesn't use any order at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use FIND_IN_SET in this particular situation:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(sum, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY sum SEPARATOR ',') 
  FROM users
  LIMIT 1
) ASC
```

FIELD expects a list of items:

```
FIELD(sum, sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4)
```

while FIND_IN_SET expects a string with a list of comma separated values:

```
FIND_IN_SET(sum, 'sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4')
```

but why not just:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

?

Comment: It was just an example, but thanks for the `FIND_IN_SET`, it works perfectly in my app now!

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
SELECT *,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sum ORDER BY sum SEPARATOR ',') FROM users LIMIT 1) as mysum
FROM users ORDER BY mysum ASC
```